# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'complement'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy trabajando con secuencias de ADN y necesito hacer una clase que tenga un método para calcular el ratio de guanina-citosina, otro para hacer el complementario de una cadena de ADN y otro más que haga el complementario y que además lo invierta, además de pruebas unitarias. El primer método consigo que me funcione, el problema viene en el segundo. Este es código que he hecho:

```
class SequenceBase:

    def __init__ (self, secuencia_nucleotidos):
        if len (secuencia_nucleotidos) == None:
            raise Exception
        else:    
            self.secuencia_nucleotidos = secuencia_nucleotidos

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.secuencia_nucleotidos.upper()

    def cadenas_iguales (self, otra_secuencia_nucleotidos):
        return (self.secuencia_nucleotidos == otra_secuencia_nucleotidos.secuencia_nucleotidos)

    def gc_content (self):   #Cálculo ratio GC --> ((G+C)/(A+T+G+C))*100
        contador_guanina = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.count("G")
        contador_citosina = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.count ("C")
        contador_adenina = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.count ("A")
        contador_timina = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.count ("T")
        proporcion_guanina_citosina = float (((contador_guanina + contador_citosina)/(contador_adenina + contador_citosina + contador_timina + contador_guanina))*100)
        return round (proporcion_guanina_citosina, 2)

    def complement (self):
        complementario = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.maketrans ("ATCG","TAGC")
        ADN_complementario = self.secuencia_nucleotidos.translate(complementario)
        return ADN_complementario
     
    def reverse_complement (self):
        ADN_complementario = self.complement ()
        cadena_invertida_ADN = reversed(ADN_complementario)
        return SequenceBase (cadena_invertida_ADN)
```

Cuando quiero hacer la prueba unitaria para complement me sale el error AtributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'complement'. Aquí están mis pruebas unitarias:

```
def test_complement (self):
    self.secuencia_ADN = "AAAACCCACGTTTGCCCG"
    self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria = "TTTTGGGTGCAAACGGGC"
    self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria = "ACCAGT"

    self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.complement (self.secuencia_ADN), self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
    self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.complement (self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria), self.secuencia_ADN)

    self.assertNotEqual (SequenceBase.complement (self.secuencia_ADN), self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria)
    self.assertNotEqual (SequenceBase.complement (self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria), self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria)

def test_reverse_complement (self):
    self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria = "AAACCAGTTGTGTACACAGT"
    self.secuencia_ADN_inversa = "TGACACATGTGTTGACCAAA"

    self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.reverse_complement (self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria),self.secuencia_ADN_inversa)
    self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.reverse_complement (self.secuencia_ADN_inversa),self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
```

Les agradecería si me pudiesen ayudar

Comment: Siempre que publiques, aquí o en otra parte, asume que será público. Cuando crees un ejemplo mínimo, asegúrate de no compartir código y datos que tu empleador no quiera que compartas. No sé si un moderador puede ayudarte sin inutilizar la pregunta.

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/22845).

Comment: Revisa los links que te pasaron.. si es pertinente, comunicate con el equipo de moderacion o con un CM....

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que posteas esta incompleto ya que haces referencia en el codigo a atributos y metodos no definidos en el codigo mostrado en el posteo.
Siendo practico el error que se te genera es porque en la funcion test_complement en la linea 5, 6, 8,9 estas llamando al atributo complement de SequenceBase a traves de la nomenclatura del punto: SequenceBase.complement
Talves tu intencion era llamar a complement como metodo del objeto SequenceBase, para eso tendrias que escribir los parentesis sin espacio entre el nombre del metodo y el parentesis.
Tu error es meramente sintactico

Seria entonces llamando a complement como metodo

```
self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.complement(self.secuencia_ADN), self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.complement(self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria), self.secuencia_ADN)

self.assertNotEqual (SequenceBase.complement(self.secuencia_ADN), self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria)
self.assertNotEqual (SequenceBase.complement(self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria), self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria)
```

realmente es bastante incomprensible el codigo y te volver a rrojar error con "self.assertNotEqual" y "self.assertEqual" ya que ambos presentan espacio.

Pasando a otra cosa sobre legibilidad de tu codigo te sugiero lo siguiente

- usa nombres acotados de variables
- usa variables para almacenar el resultado de operaciones parciales
- usa estas variables en la formula final
- el uso de "float()" en el calculo de guanina citosina es redundante porque todo resultado de division en python 3 lo convierte automaticamente a dato tipo float.
- Acompañar con comentarios facilitara la comprension y recuerdo del significado del codigo para ti en el futuro y para nosotros si pides ayudas
- El "else" del constructor es una redundancia y esta sobrando.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes ejecutar `SequenceBase.complement("AAGG")` pues `complement()` es un método de *instancia*, no de *clase*. Un método de instancia debe ser aplicado a un objeto en concreto, mientras que los métodos de clase se aplican a la clase (métodos estáticos).

El método `complement()` no tiene parámetros. El `self` en cuestión no se pasa explícitamente; simplemente identifica el objeto al que se aplica.

En este método,

```
def test_complement (self):
    self.secuencia_ADN = "AAAACCCACGTTTGCCCG"
    self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria = "TTTTGGGTGCAAACGGGC"
    self.secuencia_ADN_no_complementaria = "ACCAGT"
    
    self.assertEqual (SequenceBase.complement (self.secuencia_ADN), self.secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
    ...
```

el `self` es un objeto de clase `TestCase`; no debes interferir con él, sólo ocupar sus métodos. Por tanto, las variables que vas a ocupar son locales a la función (sin `self`).

Segundo, tienes que crear un objeto `SequenceBase` para poder usar el método `complement()`. La forma correcta es:

```
secuencia = SequenceBase(secuencia_ADN)
self.assertEqual (secuencia.complement(), secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
```

Hay que aplicar lo mismo al resto de los casos de pruebas, que quedarían así:

```
def test_reverse_complement (self):
    secuencia_ADN_complementaria = "AAACCAGTTGTGTACACAGT"
    secuencia_ADN_inversa = "TGACACATGTGTTGACCAAA"

    sec_comp = SequenceBase(secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
    sec_inv = SequenceBase(secuencia_ADN_inversa)
    self.assertEqual (sec_comp.reverse_complement(), secuencia_ADN_inversa)
    self.assertEqual (sec_inv.reverse_complement(), secuencia_ADN_complementaria)
```